# How to access my uploaded images via Wordpress Media Uploader?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

It is my first time trying to use Wordpress Media Uploader inside my theme but I am having difficulties **accessing my uploaded images**. 
Here is the problem: I can upload my images but I don't know how to **retrieve them**. 
For example when i click my upload button it uploads my image but my **textfield** is blank (it should display path to my uploaded image) so I can use it inside my theme like so :
`<?php echo $options['body_background'];?>`

My functions inside **options-page.php** look's like this:

```
//Heading Text (works fine and i can echo value out...)
function text_heading_setting(){
$options = get_option('plugin_options');
$get_options = $options['text_heading'];
echo '<input type="text" name="plugin_options[text_heading]" value="'.$get_options.'" >';
}

 //Menu Image upload field (can upload image but can't echo its path)
 function body_background_setting(){
 $options = get_option('plugin_options');
 $get_options_menu = $options['menu_background'];
 echo '<div class="uploader">
    <input type="text" name="plugin_options[menu_background]" id="menu_image_bg" value="'.$get_options_menu.'" />
    <input class="button" name="_unique_name_button" id="_unique_name_button" value="Upload" />
    </div>';
    }


   //Body Image upload field (can upload image but can't echo its path)
   function body_background_setting(){
   $options = get_option('plugin_options');
   $get_options_body_bg = $options['body_background'];
   echo '<div class="uploader">
   <input type="text" name="plugin_options[body_background]" id="menu_image_bg" value="'.$get_options_body_bg.'" />
   <input class="button" name="_unique_name_button" id="_unique_name_button" value="Upload" />
   </div>';
   }
```

**Uploader js** looks like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
 var _custom_media = true,
  _orig_send_attachment = wp.media.editor.send.attachment;

 $('.button').click(function(e) {
 var send_attachment_bkp = wp.media.editor.send.attachment;
 var button = $(this);
 var id = button.attr('id').replace('_button', '');
 _custom_media = true;
 wp.media.editor.send.attachment = function(props, attachment){
  if ( _custom_media ) {
    $("#"+id).val(attachment.url);
  } else {
    return _orig_send_attachment.apply( this, [props, attachment] );
  };
}

wp.media.editor.open(button);
return false;
});

$('.add_media').on('click', function(){
_custom_media = false;
});
});
```

Screenshot of my problem:
http://vasinternetposao.com/wordpressdevelopment/imgupload.png

Can someone help me out so I can access my uploaded images?

Comment: take a look on the link, hope this help you http://webomnizz.com/blog/php/how-to-use-wordpress-uploader-into-your-theme/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try adding `esc_url()` to the value

```
//Menu Image upload field (can upload image but can't echo its path)
 function body_background_setting(){
 $options = get_option('plugin_options');
 $get_options_menu = $options['menu_background'];
 echo '<div class="uploader">
    <input type="text" name="plugin_options[menu_background]" id="menu_image_bg" value="'.esc_url($get_options_menu).'" />
    <input class="button" name="_unique_name_button" id="_unique_name_button" value="Upload" />
    </div>';
    }


   //Body Image upload field (can upload image but can't echo its path)
   function body_background_setting(){
   $options = get_option('plugin_options');
   $get_options_body_bg = $options['body_background'];
   echo '<div class="uploader">
   <input type="text" name="plugin_options[body_background]" id="menu_image_bg" value="'.esc_url($get_options_body_bg).'" />
   <input class="button" name="_unique_name_button" id="_unique_name_button" value="Upload" />
   </div>';
   }
```